# How to efficiently expanding arrays in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My question is how to efficiently expand an array, by copying itself many times. I am trying to expand my survey samples to the full size dataset, by copying every sample N times. N is the influence factor that signed to the sample. 
So I wrote two loops to do this task (script pasted below). It works, but  is slow. My sample size is 20,000, and try to expand it into 3 million full size.. is there any function I can try? Thank you for your help!

----My script----

```
lines = np.asarray(person.read().split('\n'))
df_array = np.asarray(lines[0].split(' '))
for j in range(1,len(lines)-1):
    subarray = np.asarray(lines[j].split(' '))
    factor = int(round(float(subarray[-1]),0))
    for i in range(1,factor):
        df_array = np.vstack((df_array, subarray))
print len(df_array)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can try to load data all together with `numpy.loadtxt`.

Then, to repeat according to the last column, use `numpy.repeat`:

```
>>> data = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
...                  [4, 5, 6]])
>>> np.repeat(data, data[:,-1], axis=0)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Finally, if you need to round `data[:,-1]`, replace it with `np.round(data[:,-1]).astype(int)`.

Answer (score 1):

Stacking numpy arrays over and over is not very efficient, because they're not really optimized for dynamic growth like that. Every time you vstack, it's allocating a whole new chunk of memory for the size of your data at that point.

Use lists then build your array right at the end, maybe something with a generator like this:

```
def upsample(stream):
    for line in stream:
        rec = line.strip().split()
        factor = int(round(float(rec[-1]),0))
        for i in xrange(factor):
            yield rec

df_array = np.array(list(upsample(person)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The concept you are looking for is called `broadcasting`. It allows you to fill an `n dimensional` array with an `n-1 dimensional` array's contents.

Looking at your code example, you are calling `np.vstack()` in a loop. Broadcasting will eliminate the loop.

For example, if you have a 1D array of `n` elements,

```
>>> n = 5
>>> df_array = np.arange(n)
>>> df_array
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

you can then create a new `n x 10` array:

```
>>> bigger_array = np.empty([10,n])
>>> bigger_array[:] = df_array
>>> bigger_array
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.]])
```

So with a single line of code, you can fill it with the contents of the smaller array.

**bigger_array[:] = df_array**

NB. Avoid using python lists. They are far, far slower than the Numpy ndarray.

Comment: Thank you. If my understand is right, you are saying apply bigger_array[:] to expand the small sample. After expanding them one by one, I also need to combine all of them into a big data set. At that stage, it is not expanding, is combine.. is there any efficient way than using np.vstack()?

Comment: The most efficient way is likely to use 'np.empty()' to allocate the space/memory for your end dataset and then load data & broadcast within that using slice indexing. This will be inherently faster than using loops in Python.